# how to view 3D objects from medical ct scan in itkwidgets using view

Tags: python, image-processing, itk

i am trying to use itkwidgets for my project.
i followed this example

https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/itkwidgets/blob/master/examples/3DImage.ipynb

this example work perfectly, but when i try pass a 3d numpy array just a transparent cube is plotted in 3d.
[image]

but if i take the same 3d image and plot single single images they plot fine.
[image]

[image]

Can someone please explain why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your image to ITK format first.

```
image = itk.GetImageViewFromArray(np_array)
view(image, rotate=True, axes=True, ...)
```

Comment: i have converted that numpy array to itk format and still i just get a cube, i have tried itk.GetImageFromarray(), itk.GetImageViewFromArray() i am still getting a cube. i even set the spacing to original spacing. i have also converted image into np.astype(uint8).

Comment: it would also help us a lot if itk creates some tutorial for segmenting ct scans and viewing them in 3D. that's what i am trying to do right now.

Comment: If the other parameters of `view`, e.g. `vmin=4000, vmax=17000` are inappropriate for your image, that could explain the fully-transparent cube.

Comment: i did play around with those parameters. but still ended up with a cube. i segmented the lungs and even tried with segmented lungs. even though the threshold of images ranges from -1024 to -600 it doesnt show up in that view output. it shows from 0 to 0 i dont know why.

Comment: If you make a self-contained notebook which reproduces the problem, you could submit an issue: https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/itkwidgets/issues

Comment: Thanks a lot. i will submit a self contained jupyter notebook to that issues page.